# If number in range(x, y) contains digit, print number(s)

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the best way to print out all the numbers in for example range(0, 1000) containing digit x?

And what is the best way of returning the number of numbers that contains the digit x in for example  range(0, 1000)?

Comment: Loop through the numbers in the range, convert the number to a string, if the string contains `x` then print it.

Comment: But it is a forum where u can ask programing releated questions right?


Never asked someone to write the code for me, the response @Barmar gave was enough to get me going, thanks

Comment: if you just need to know how many numbers there are its pretty easy `4*(1+10^3)` (I think at least)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this do the job?

```
x = '3'
number_list = []

for i in range(1,10001):
        number_list.append(str(i))

x_numbers = [y for y in number_list if x in y]

print(len(x_numbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be as suggested by Barmar:

```
x=5
y=12
digit_check=1

for Int in range(x,y):
    if str(digit_check) in str(Int):
        print Int
```

Answer (score 0):

Compute how many numbers do *not* have the required digit in *any* of the four locations.  Subtract from the total.

```
print 10000 - 10000 * 9/10 * 9/10 * 9/10 * 9/10
```